# Unable to make any minio operations from a different container to the Minio container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, minio

I'm trying to build a containerized application that will basically read from a storage service do some operations and write a "processed" file into the same storage service.
I tried using NFS as a storage service but hit a few bottlenecks which led me to Minio as a storage service, which works out very well for me since I'm already familiar with AWS S3.

So I spun up a Minio container and basically wrote a simple python script which will basically check for .csv files that have been uploaded in the last 60 seconds.
I tested this locally and it worked flawlessly.

This is the sample code -

```
import time
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import ResponseError

# Initialize the Minio client
host = "minio_server:9000"
access_key = "ROOTNAME"
secret_key="CHANGEME123"
client = Minio (host, access_key=access_key,
    secret_key=secret_key, secure=False)
# Set the name of the bucket to monitor
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'

# Set the interval for checking the bucket (in seconds)
check_interval = 60

while True:
  # Get the list of objects in the bucket
  objects = client.list_objects(bucket_name, prefix='', recursive=True)
  
  # Check the time of each object
  for obj in objects:
    # Check if the object is a CSV file
    if obj.object_name.endswith('.csv'):
      # Check if the object was uploaded in the last 60 seconds
      current_time = time.time()
      if current_time - obj.last_modified.timestamp() < check_interval:
        print(f'Found new CSV file: {obj.object_name}')
  
  # Sleep for the specified interval before checking again
  time.sleep(check_interval)
```

And this works exactly as intended.

So next I containerized this application and created a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3
#RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get -y install tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y libenchant1c2a

RUN apt install git -y

RUN pip3 install \
  argparse \
  boto3 \
  numpy==1.20.3 \
  scipy \
  pandas \
  scikit-learn \
  matplotlib \
  plotly \
  kaleido \
  fpdf \
  regex \
  pyenchant \
  minio \
  pythonping\
  openpyxl

RUN git clone https://github.com/nedap/dateinfer.git && \
  cd dateinfer && \
  pip3 install .


ADD core.py /core.py

CMD ["/core.py"]

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

Note- I need the other dependencies for the actual application that I'm going to write once this test passes.

I created a Docker-compose.yaml file to club the two containers.

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  minio_server:
    image:  quay.io/minio/minio
    networks:
      - appnet
    container_name: minio_server
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    command: server --address ":9000" --console-address ":9001" /data
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=ROOTNAME
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=CHANGEME123
    volumes:
      - /minio/data:/data
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
      - 9000:9000
  
  minio_core_server:
    image: miniocore:latest
    networks:
      - appnet
    depends_on:
      - minio_server
    
networks:
  appnet:
    name: appnet
```

And obviously I Made some changes to the source code to do something super simple -

```
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import ResponseError

# Set the URL of the Minio server

minio_url = "minio_server:9000"

# Set the access key and secret key for the Minio server
access_key = "ROOTNAME"
secret_key = "CHANGEME123"

# Initialize the Minio client
client = Minio(minio_url,
              access_key=access_key,
              secret_key=secret_key,
              secure=True)

# Set the name of the bucket
imput_bucket= client.make_bucket('sample.bucket')
```

But I'm getting the following error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
minio_core_server_1  |     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
minio_core_server_1  | urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='minio_server', port=9000): Max retries exceeded with url: /sample.bucket (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)')))

Trouble shooting steps that I tried:

I initially thought that the service container is unable to establish a connection between the service container and the Minio container:

So I tried to ping the Minio container from the application from the service container

```
from minio import Minio
#from minio.error import ResponseError

# Set the URL of the Minio server
from pythonping import ping

ping("minio_server", verbose=True)
```

and this is the response -

minio_core_server_1  | Reply from 192.168.192.2, 29 bytes in 0.03ms
minio_core_server_1  | Reply from 192.168.192.2, 29 bytes in 0.01ms
minio_core_server_1  | Reply from 192.168.192.2, 29 bytes in 0.01ms
minio_core_server_1  | Reply from 192.168.192.2, 29 bytes in 0.01ms

SO it's in fact able to establish a connection with the Minio container

Comment: When you say "I created a Docker-compose.yaml file to club the two containers," what do you mean by "club"? I assume that you don't mean you beat them to death with a heavy stick.